# Several android developers same project : how to deal with (maps,places,translate) api key?

Tags: android, api, google-api, google-places-api, collaboration

I've an android app on github, and there's a few day another developer fork my project.
I need some help with the api key...
This app use 3 different API : maps, places et translate.

The other developer create his own api, referencing my project and it works great... only for maps. He receives the maps tiles without problems.

But, when he use places api with his own api key, he has the error "**This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.**"

What's wrong exactly ? Is it the good way to tell him to create his own api key?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your personal accounts; just create a company/project account and create all API keys for that one account. Never tie in a project with specific developers.

Comment: So, each developpers will have his own api key by accessing on the console with the project account ?

Comment: No, let's say your project is called ABC. Create a Google account for ABC, and for every API you need or other developers need, request it from the ABC Google account.

Comment: Ok, but when i create a new key, i need to write the certificate fingerprints and this fingerprint is different according to the developers right ? So which fingerprints must i use ?

Comment: My bad, i understood. I don't have to write the fingerprint, "Any application allowed"